# How to create a "backdoor" for administrator, to be able to log in as anohter user and see information?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I am creating an online survey tool.

As an administrator, i would like to see what the users have answered and also be able to answer on their behalf. The system get's a users answers and other information based on his/her username, when they are logged in, using the built in membership provider.

There are currently three roles: Administrator, Moderator and Respondent

If i would like to show my administrator a list of users,

how would it be possible to create a "backdoor" for the administrator, so that he can "log" in as the user, see the users answers etc ? (Just like the user would be able to if he was logged in to his own account).

When answering and retrieving quyestions, the system is bound to `User.Identity.Name

---

My suggestion on how to solve this:

Currently, when i want to retrive a users answers i use the following code:

```
Firma_ID = db.Firma.Single(x => x.CVR_nummer == User.Identity.Name).firma_id;
var answers = db.Tabelform_Answers.Where(x => x.question_id == model.Question_ID && x.respondent == Firma_ID);
```

This is because i have a table named Firma, that has a column referencing to a users Name, called CVR_Nummer. I then retrieve all the records in the Tabelform_Answers table, that match question_id and Firma_ID (A users answers for a specific question).

Instead of using `Firma_ID = db.Firma.Single(x => x.CVR_nummer == User.Identity.Name).firma_id;

to retrive the Firma_ID of a given user, i could store it in the Session upon Login. When i want to view a specific users Answers as Administrator, i would then just change Firma_ID in the Session. Changing Firma_ID in the Session would only be allowed through a controller which has the following code:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
```

Also, i would set the Session timeout to be the same as the Authentication timeout.

Can somebody tell me which pros and cons of this solution? Are there any other ways of storing a "global" variable for a Session? (Firma_ID)?

Thanks

Comment: I have not tried anything, because i am looking for suggestions on how to do it. I am not sure i would be possible to change the MemberShipUser when logged in, as the administrator would loose his rights to other things. Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take another look.

Comment: I think you have a design issue here. In a survey system, an Admin is nothing like a Respondent. They should not see the same interface. (I develop/manage a survey system full-time as my job :))

Comment: What use is a survey to anyone if someone else can just trundle in and change the answers? Why would you want to? You didn't like them? Respondent is a role, add the role tou yoir user log in as one. seeing the answers even though you aren't them, doesn't require you to log in as them, unless you shouldn't be looking.

Comment: @ChristianWattengård The admin has his own interface to add/edit questions etc. I would just like to reuse the code to answer questions (respondent interface) and therefore i dont want to build it from scratch. Ill mark your answer as a question, even though it isnt the answer im going for.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Please read my question again. Respondent is a role. Administrator should be able to answer on a respondents behalf. If a respondent doesnt understand a question, he can call the administrator, which can explain the question and also answer it for him. There will be 20 people calling different companies trying to get them to answer the survey. Theese people should, like the admin, also be able to answer on a company/respondent's behalf. Thats why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to log in as your users, I went for a ticket-method.
I have a special login-page that can take a ticket-id. This ticket is created in the admin-gui when the admin wants to log in as another user. The login-page checks the ticket in the database, logs in the wanted user, and then deletes/marks the ticket as used. As an added security, a ticket is only valid for 10 seconds after creation.

Another option is to make answers from users available from the admin-gui...

Comment: When you log in as the user, do you have to log out and log in again as administrator, to get your rights back? Can you provide some links for this approach?

Comment: Well, no. Because it's two separate systems. The admin-gui has it's own sessionstore.

Comment: And when thinking about it. Your users and administrators don't actually have anything in common. So a separate system for administration would be the way to go in this case. Let the admin look-up users in his own interface.

Comment: So the admin GUI is an external application?

Comment: No it's a MVC 3 app. The apps share a Core library, to try to keep it DRY ;)

Answer (score 0):

also you can do in your log-in script override

so you have at present something like

if user name and password match string then user is logged in and based on this you get user permissions

instead have admin page,
where you can select user and then you can apply permissions of the user instead of admin.